# orm на фронте, в pwa?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, frontend, orm, framework7

Подскажите библиотеки orm (если я правильно понял - это то, что мне нужно) которые можно использовать на фронте с локальной бд sqlite3. Делаю приложение на cordova (по сути webview +плагины) с framework7. У меня куча объектов разных типов, хранящихся локально, для которых получается куча однотипного кода по сохранению в бд, чтению из бд, отображению и редактированию на страницах из двух шаблонов - форма списка и форма элемента. И еще поддержка миграции + синхронизация бд с сервером. Как-то хочется это соптимизировать.

Comment: [Тыц](https://habr.com/ru/articles/778720/) и по ссылкам, по ссылкам!